# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'features' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to add a row to my dataframe using a function

```
features = pd.read_csv("Work.csv")
```

here is the function :

```
def classify(Res,O,S,R,Rear,F,L,B):    
     features = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[Res,O,S,R,Rear,F,L,B]]), 
                      columns=['Resolution','OS','Storage','RAM',
                       'RearCamera','FrontCamera','LoudSpeaker','Battery'])\
                  .append(features, ignore_index=True)
```

when I call the function as :

```
classify(19283,"lolipop","fr","gg","ff",0,0,0)
```

I get the following error :

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7c16987ef1b2> in <module>()
----> 1 classify(19283,"lolipop","fr","gg","ff",0,0,0)

<ipython-input-3-c620ec52544a> in classify(Res, O, S, R, Rear, F, L, B)
      1 def classify(Res,O,S,R,Rear,F,L,B):
      2 
----> 3     features = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[Res,O,S,R,Rear,F,L,B]]), columns=['Resolution','OS','Storage','RAM','RearCamera','FrontCamera','LoudSpeaker','Battery']).append(features, ignore_index=True)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'features' referenced before assignment
```

How do I fix it ?

Comment: How can you append `features` to `features` if `features` has not been defined yet? It is not clear what you want to do, but removing `.append(features, ignore_index=True)` would eliminate the error message.

Comment: I want to add a new row in a pre existing data frame using a function , i have defined feature as :   features = pd.read_csv("Work.csv")

Comment: Please add the missing line to your example. The problem that you encounter depends on the location of that line.

Comment: I made made a change . Hope it is more clearer now .